# How to tell how many files match description with * in unix

Tags: string, bash, unix

Pretty simple question: say I have a set of files:

```
a1.txt
a2.txt
a3.txt
b1.txt
```

And I use the following command:

```
ls a*.txt
```

It will return:

```
a1.txt a2.txt a3.txt
```

Is there a way in a bash script to tell how many results will be returned when using the * pattern. In the above example if I were to use a*.txt the answer should be 3 and if I used *1.txt the answer should be 2.

Comment: "Delimiter"?  You mean "pattern" probably.

Comment: @MarkEdgar Yes i do , thank you i will make that edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ls` in combination with `wc`:

```
ls a*.txt | wc -l
```

The `ls` command lists the matching files one per line, and `wc -l` counts the number of lines.

Comment: Cool, is there a way to assign this number to a variable, ie num=ls a*.txt | wc -l where num becomes 3?

Comment: Sure, use backticks: `num=\`ls a*.txt | wc -l\`` (be careful not to put any spaces around the `=`) Then you can use `$num` in your script.

Comment: Cheers, I will mark your answer as correct in about 3 minutes.

Comment: Isn't the `$()` approach favored over using backticks? I've always used backticks, but get dinged for mentioning them instead of the `$()` -- especially over on http://unix.stackexchange.com :-) `$()` works better with nested constructs I guess (not an issue here).

Comment: Yeah, I suppose `$()` is often better but I'm old school.

Comment: `ls a*.txt` will print several columns if that is possible. Use `ls -1 a*.txt` instead.

Comment: @steffen: Not when writing to a pipe (see my comment on Levon's answer).

Answer (score 5):

**Comment on using `ls`:**

1. I see all the other answers attempt this by parsing the output of
   `ls`. This is very unpredictable because this breaks when you have
   file names with "unusual characters" (*e.g.* spaces).
2. Another pitfall would be, it is `ls` implementation dependent. A
   particular implementation might format output differently.

There is a very nice discussion on the pitfalls of parsing ls output on the  [bash wiki maintained by Greg Wooledge](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

**Solution using bash arrays**

For the above reasons, using bash syntax would be the more reliable option. You can use a glob to populate a bash array with all the matching file names. Then you can ask bash the length of the array to get the number of matches. The following snippet should work.

```bsh
files=(a*.txt) && echo "${#files[@]}"
```

To save the number of matches in a variable, you can do:

```bsh
files=(a*.txt)
count="${#files[@]}"
```

One more advantage of this method is you now also have the matching files in an array which you can iterate over.

**Note:** Although I keep repeating *bash syntax* above, I believe the above solution applies to all *sh*-family of shells.

Comment: There is a more in-depth article on parsing ls on the bash wiki: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 4):

You can't know ahead of time, but you can count how many results are returned. I.e.

```
  ls -l *.txt | wc -l
```

`ls -l` will display the directory entries matching the specified wildcard,  wc -l  will give you the count.

You can save the value of this command in a shell variable with either

```
  num=$(ls * | wc -l)
```

or

```
  num=`ls -l *.txt | wc -l`
```

and then use `$num` to access it. The first form is preferred.

Comment: `wc -w` isn't reliable when file names contain spaces. `wc -l` is a tad more robust.

Comment: @larsmans Ah .. never come across that problem, thanks (and I'll keep that in mind)! I'll update my answer. I think in that case I should use `ls -l`

Comment: @Levon: Note that `ls`, when writing to a pipe, never tries to "format" the listing into columns. (At least, not in any `ls` updated in the last 25 years or so - you can still find really old implementations where you need to use `-1` to make it do the right thing.)

Comment: @GregHewgill I just noticed that it doesn't seem to make a difference when piped, you are right. I guess I was just applying from using `ls` for displaying files (in which case the `-l` of course makes a difference).

Answer (score 2):

I like suvayu's answer, but there's no need to use an array:

```
count() { echo $#; }
count *
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to count files that might have unpredictable names, e.g. containing new-lines, non-printable characters etc., I would use the `-print0` option of `find` and `awk` with `RS='\0'`:

```
num=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | awk -v RS='\0' 'END { print NR }')
```

Adjust the options to `find` to refine the count, e.g. if the criteria is files starting with a lower-case `a` with `.txt` extension in the current directory, use:

```
find . -type f -name 'a*.txt' -maxdepth 1 -print0
```